# Iteration for a non-sequential column

Tags: plsql

can some one help me...

I have to create,for each "Costumer", a iterator for a non-sequential ID to update the "version" column.

I need a cursor or something else?

Can i get some help?

Example:

```
ID   COSTUMER         VERSION
12    ANNA                 1
24    ANNA                 4
25    ANNA                 5
60    ANNA                11
```

I want to correct the version to be sequential

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not clear to me at least what you are meaning by a "non-sequential" ID.

Comment: Please be more detailed and provide an example

Comment: ID   COSTUMER  VERSION
12    ANNA                 1
24    ANNA                 4
25    ANNA                 5
60    ANNA                11

I what to correct the version to be sequential.

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it - why do the versions go 1, 4, 5, 11 - what is the **rule** here?

Comment: Correction of data..so the version got in that form

Comment: Ah - so you want to change the versions to 1,2,3,4?

Comment: yes...the true form must be 1,2,3,4...

Comment: OK< I have given an answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: There was no completion of this problem. There was no need to update the versions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use code something like this:

```
begin
    for r in ( select id, row_number() over (partition by name order by version) as rn
               from costumer
             )
    loop  
        update costumer
        set version = r.rn
        where id = r.id;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

The `partition by` is there because I have assumed you want to have the sequence start from 1 for 'ANNA', then start from 1 again for customer 'JANE' etc.  If not you can remove that part.

Comment: why loop round a cursor when you could do this in a single merge statement?

Comment: Because I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to do it via a single MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO costumer tgt
  USING (SELECT ID,
                costumer,
                VERSION,
                ROWID row_id,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY costumer ORDER BY VERSION) new_version
         FROM   costumer) src
  ON (tgt.rowid = src.rowid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET tgt.version = src.new_version;
```

Comment: Btw, this merge statement joins on the rowid (something I wouldn't normally recommend), but otherwise the join condition would be on costumer and version, but Oracle doesn't allow you to update columns that are in the join clause, which would prevent us from upating the version column.